# Web Form off of Master not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm new to ASP.NET and seems I screwed up my Web Form page that is based off of a Master.
It seems I mixed some invalid html codes but can't figure out why.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Clips.aspx.cs" Inherits="Clip.Clips" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="entityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ClipEnt" DefaultContainerName="ClipEnt" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Clips" EntityTypeFilter="Clip" OnSelecting="EntityDataSource_Selecting">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="entityDataSource">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

            <div>
            <h1>Sending Email</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>From:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>From EMail:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="138px" 
                        Width="467px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Email" 
                        onclick="btnSend_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: In your code snippet there only is the closing of a form tag. Try to remove that. But it is just a guess, you don't what the problem is, or what error message you get.

Comment: says I have more than needed "runat=" but I don't know which one to get rid of.

Comment: Keep the one in your Master page, ASP.NET Web forms need to have only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the masterpage you have something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You only need to have this stripped markup in the content page. Notice that I have removed `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and `<form>` tags from content page - they will be rendered from **Site.Master** master page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Clips.aspx.cs" Inherits="Clip.Clips" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="entityDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=ClipEnt" DefaultContainerName="ClipEnt" EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Clips" EntityTypeFilter="Clip" OnSelecting="EntityDataSource_Selecting">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="entityDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <div>
        <h1>Sending Email</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>From:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>From EMail:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>To Email:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToEmail" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Message:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="138px"
                        Width="467px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Email"
                        OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points to remember when developing an asp.net web site -

1. asp.net web forms can contain only one `form` tag with the attribute `runat='server'`. So, when a web form inherits from a masterpage, it inherits the `form` tag from the master page. therefore, no need to add a `form` tag separately to the web form.
2. Common parts of the page should be placed in the master page, where as changing parts should be placed in the web forms that inherit the master page. Site headers and footers are static to every page. so they should be placed on the master page. contents of the web site changes from page to page. so they should be placed on the web forms that inherit the master page.
3. Links to common resources, i.e. site style sheets and javascript files should also be placed once in the masterpage. web forms that inherit the masterpage will automatically inherit them.

these are some of the things by following which you can easily develop web forms with master pages.